# HTTP Response 412 - can you include content?

Tags: rest, http, atom-feed, http-status-code-412

I am building a RESTful data store and leveraging Conditional GET and PUT.  During a conditional PUT the client can include the Etag from a previous GET on the resource and if the current representation doesn't match the server will return the HTTP status code of 412 (Precondition Failed).  Note this is an Atom based server/protocol.

My question is, when I return the 412 status can I also include the new representation of the resource or must the user issue a new GET?  The HTTP spec doesn't seem to say yes or no and neither does the Atom spec (although their example shows an empty entity body on the response).  It seems pretty wasteful not to return the new representation and make the client specifically GET it.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although conditional GETs and PUTs are summarized as 'conditional requests' they are very different conceptually. Conditional GETs are a performance optimization and conditional PUTs are a concurrency control mechanism. It is hard to discuss them together.

To your question regarding the conditional GET: If you send GET and include an If-None-Match header the server will send 200 Ok if the resource has changed and 304 Not Modified if it did not (if the condition failed). 412 is only to be used with conditional PUTs.

UPDATE: It seems I misread the question slightly. To your point regarding the 'refresh' of the local copy upon a failed conditional PUT: It might well be that a cache already has the newest version and that your refresh-GET will be served from some cache. Having the server return the current entity with the 412 might actually give you worse performance.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't following your initial answer - but your point about the possible intermediate cache is a very good one.  Honestly the best answer I've seen so far.

Answer (score 3):

No, technically you should not. Error codes are generally to specify that something has gone wrong. Although nothing would stop you from returning content (and in fact, some errors like a 404 return a pretty page that says You didn't find what you're looking for), the point of the response is not to return other content, but to return something that tells you what was wrong. Technically you also should not return that data because you passed the If-None-Match: etag (I'm assuming that's what you passed?)

On another note, do you really need to optimize away one additional http call?

The more I think about this, the more I'm convinced it's a bad idea - Are you going to return the content on any other errors? PUT semantics are to PUT. GET semantics should be used for GET.

Comment: Optimizing away one HTTP call can easily mean millions of saved requests a day - so yes I would be in favor of that.  POST semantics are to POST - yet it's completely valid to return content on a successful POST, so I don't agree with your argument there.

Comment: You're not doing a POST, you're doing a PUT. POST semantics are different than both, and it's valid to return content on a post, because the semantics state: The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT requests is
   reflected in the different meaning of the request-target.  The URI in
   a POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed
   entity.  That resource might be a data-accepting process, a gateway
   to some other protocol, or a separate entity that accepts
   annotations.
This means that POST has the flexibility to return content unrelated to the URI.

Answer (score 2):

If the number of additional requests incurred, due to an extra request after an update conflict, is significant enough for you to have performance concerns, then I would suggest you might have issues with the granularity of your resources.

Do you really expect millions of times a day multiple users will be editing the same resource simultaneously?  Maybe you need to be storing delta changes to the resource instead updating the resource directly.  If there really is that much contention for these resources then aren't users going to be constantly working on out of date data.

If your problem was that your resource contains the last-modified date and last-modified user and you had to do a GET after every PUT then I would be more convinced of the need to twist the rules.

However, I think the performance hit of the extra request is worth it for the clarity to the client developer.